# DataContext with DataLoadOptions and LoadWith returns wrong amount of entries

Tags: windows-phone-7, datacontext

Imagine the following scenario: I have two classes in a one-to-many relationship and I try load all objects from one class and at the same time also load all associated objects. Here is the skeletal structure for both of those classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    //... id and other members omitted

    [Association(Name = "FK_Parent_Children", Storage = "_entries", ThisKey = "Id")]
    public EntitySet<Child> Children {
        get { return _children; }
    }
    private readonly EntitySet<Child> _children = new EntitySet<Child>();
}

public class Child
{
    //... id and other members omitted

    [Column]
    internal int? _belongId;

    private EntityRef<Parent> _belong;
    [Association(Name = "FK_Parent_Children", Storage = "_belong", ThisKey = "_belongId", OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Parent Belong
    {
        get { return _belong.Entity; }
        set { _belong.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

And here comes the code I tried for loading all the objects:

```
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

    var options = new DataLoadOptions();    
    options.AssociateWith<Parent>(c => c.Children.OrderByDescending(x => x.Born).Take(100));    
    options.LoadWith<Parent>(m => m.Children);
    context.LoadOptions = options;

    var parents = context.Parents.OrderBy(m => m.LastName).ToList();
    return parents; 
}
```

Interestingly a maximum of exactly one "Child" is loaded into the EntitySet all the time although there are often more objects associated with a single "Parent". Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the cause for this erratic behavior and finally gave up on doing it this way.